# Grouping together a list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to group the self.L list into groups of five and then reverse  both individual groups
I want my output to look as follows

```
    step1.(group the  list into two section of five)

    [[1,3,5,67,8],[90,100,45,67,865]]

    step2.(reverse the numbers within the two groups)

    [[8,67,5,3,1],[865,67,45,100,90]]
```

The code I have

```
        class Flip():
    def __init__(self,answer):
        self.Answer = answer
        self.matrix = None
        self.L = [1,3,5,67,8,90,100,45,67,865,]


    def flip(self):
        if self.Answer == 'h':
            def grouping(self):
                for i in range(0, len(self.L), 5):
                   self.matrix.append(self.L[i:i+5])
            print(self.matrix)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    ans = input("Type h for horizontal flip")
    work = Flip(ans)
    work.flip()
```

When I run the code my output is

```
    None
```

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indentation first.

Comment: Yes, please revise your code and ensure it is all structured appropriately. Also, setting `self.matrix = None` is going to give you problems based on how you are using it. You seem to want to use this as a list, so just initialize it as one: `self.matrix = []`

Comment: You define the function `grouping` inside the `flip` method (a closure), but 1/ you don't call `grouping()`, nor do you return any result from `grouping`. So you just print the still empty matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create nested lists with 5 elements in each one, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [1,3,5,67,8,90,100,45,67,865]
new_list = [lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]
```

Then to reverse the order of the values in the nested lists you can use `.reverse()`

```
for elem in new_list:
    elem.reverse()
print (new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[8, 67, 5, 3, 1], [865, 67, 45, 100, 90]]
```

Comment: You can simply reverse in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we receive the initial list in the variable `L`:

```
L = [1,3,5,67,8,90,100,45,67,865]

L1 = L[0:5]
L2 = L[5:10]
L=[L1,L2]
print (L)
L1.reverse()
L2.reverse()
L=[L1,L2]
print (L)
```